# Laravel 5 - route not being redirected too

Tags: laravel-5

I have set up some resourceful routing with an additional route to email a PDF.

```
Route::model('projects.document', 'Document');
Route::resource('projects.document', 'Docs\DocumentController', ['except' => ['index', 'show']]);
Route::post('projects/{projects}/document/{document}/emailPdf', array('as' => 'projects.document.emailPdf', 'uses' => 'Docs\DocumentController@emailPdf'));
```

This all works fine but I am having one problem.  On my projects.documents edit page, I have a modal which allows emails to be entered and then when you click send, the emails are sent to the email addresses.  Once again, this all works.

My email function looks like the following

```
public function emailPdf(Project $project)
{
    $emailList = Input::get('email-select');
    try{
        $pdf = new DocumentPDF($orientation='P', $unit='mm', $format='A4', $unicode=true, $encoding='UTF-8', $diskcache=false, $pdfa=false, $project);
        $pdf->storePdf();
        $pdf->sendEmail($emailList);
        $users = User::lists('userEmail');
        return View::make('document.edit', compact('project', 'users'));
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        var_dump("ERROR " . $e);
    }
}
```

When an email is sent, the modal closes, and I am still on the documents edit page like I want it to be.  However, the url changes to

```
http://localhost:8000/projects/23/document/2/emailPdf
```

I know this is the route for the emailPdf function, but once an email is sent, this should go back to

```
http://localhost:8000/projects/23/document/2/edit
```

How can I get it to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Does your email form submit via ajax?

Comment: no, have it in a form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are just creating a new view on same url and not actually redirecting to http://localhost:8000/projects/23/document/2/edit. Instead of

```
return View::make('document.edit', compact('project', 'users'));
```

put

```
return redirect->route(<your root alias here>);
```

or in this case simply

```
return redirect->back();
```

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#redirects